# Can I use photos of my own dogs that were taken by someone else?

Tags: legal, copyright

I recently started a pet accessory business and wanted to use some pictures of my dogs that had been given to me as a Xmas gift last year.

The person who took the photos says they own the copyright and is asking me to give them credit or remove the pictures from my website.  Do they own the copyright and what should I do?

Comment: Hey, props to you for *asking* vs just doing first! Photographers appreciate it! Find a photographer who might like some of your accessories, maybe a barter is possible!

Comment: What do you have against giving credit?  It seems quite kind of them to let you continue to use the photos for free if you merely give credit.  To me I'm wondering why complicate this matter when it seems like continuing to use the photos but giving credit is actually not going to be much of a problem?

Comment: Unless you now have a hate-hate relationship it seems a very little thing to give photo credits, regardless of whether she is acting unreasonably in seeking to retract a "my word is my bond" agreement. This only seems unreasonable if the cost to you of giving way to what may be an unreasonable demand is greater than the gains of "walking the second mile".

Comment: Thanks for the great legal advice. I really appreciate it! To some others- As for the reasons why I do not want her name anywhere on my site is none of your concern. I asked for legal advice and that is what I was looking for. Not to be criticized on why.

Comment: Why would you knowingly involve your business in a controversy? Spend a few hundred bucks on a commercial photographer and get photos that are 100% yours to do with as you please.

Comment: I took photos myself and used them. The end.

Answer (score 27):

> She had given me verbal permission to use the photos for whatever I wanted, but now that we aren't close anymore, she has decided otherwise.

This comment makes the situation a bit more hairy legal-wise. The fact is that the copyright of a photograph always belongs to the photographer regardless of the photo's subject, apart from some edge cases that don't apply here (e.g. a photograph of another photograph or painting), unless the photographer explicitly agrees or has agreed otherwise.

What makes this tricky is that the photographer gave you permission to use the photographs as you see fit, but revoked it later. Owning the copyright doesn't let one retract usage permissions at will.

Whether she is legally allowed to revoke the permission depends on your jurisdiction, and if you were to go to court, the result would probably depend on the judge and how good the lawyers are in presenting the matter. Since there's no written contract, she could also deny ever giving you a do-what-you-want license.

That said, the legality of the matter is mostly irrelevant. Neither of you are unlikely to go to court over a trivial matter like this. What it comes down to is ethics and practicalities: Would it be ethically correct to use the photos against the photographer's wishes? Is it ethically correct for the photographer to revoke the permission she has already granted?

Since you seem to be unwilling to even mention the photographer's name on your web site (otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question), I'm assuming there's quite a lot of bad blood between the two of you. If you do use the photos against her will, regardless of whether it's legally or ethically allowed, how much would it make the situation worse?

In practice I would suggest not to escalate the situation any further and just either credit her on the web site as she wishes, get someone else take photos of the dogs, or spend a couple of dollars on stock photography.

Comment: +1.  Going the legal route usually incurs massive cost on the relationship side.  Just because it is legal doesn't mean it is good :)

Comment: While not directly relevant since OP seems to be from the US.  Moral rights, like the right of attribution, are seperate from copyright.  In some countries the former are non-transferable.

Comment: I thank you so much for being professional and for giving me the advice I was looking for.  I decided to take some new pics to use instead. I did not know anything about the legal aspect before speaking with you so that was why I asked the question in the first place.  I thank you very much for not criticizing me as to why I didn't want the girls name on my site and I thank you for explaining to me the legality if I were to use them. Again thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are in the United States, the photographer owns all rights to images they take unless they were done under a contract that assigns those rights to someone else or under a work-for-hire agreement. It doesn't sound like in this case there was any written agreement or that the person who took the photos was your employee with the specific job of taking photos for you at the time the images were created.

If you use any images without permission of the copyright holder you could be liable for damages if the owner of the images chooses to sue you. If the owner has registered the images with the U.S. copyright office you could also be liable for punitive damages.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! Yes in the US.  It was a friend at the time who took the pics of my dogs. I gave her a nice Xmas gift and so she offered to come to my house to take pictures of my dogs. (She dabled in photography as a hobby).  So there was not a contract given. I'm guessing the only thing I can do is take them down, or give her photo credit for the 2 pics.

Comment: giving credit does not solve the issue.   a *written* contractual agreement giving you rights to use them this way is what you need.

Comment: Written contract is nice to have if you think you may get sued, but not mandatory.  Verbal contracts are technically valid too but just hard to prove in court.  Think Hoefler&Co vs Frere-Jones.  It sounds like this is a "friend", albeit not a close friend.  How likely is this really to go to court?  Is it a particularly litigious friend?  I can't help but feel most people are over-complicating this and just assuming the friend is going to sue.  Copyright is a civil law, so you're not in trouble unless the other party *decides* to take legal action.

Comment: (continued) From what I've read here I don't see any reason the friend would sue if Julie gave credit.  YMMV

Comment: Nowhere does the answer say the other party is *likely* to sue. But the possibility is always there and should be considered. Especially since the nature of this site means others with similar questions about using images they do not own may be considering using images owned by someone who *is* more likely to sue them.

Comment: And this specific situation looks to me like the photographer is an *ex-friend* who has had a falling out with the OP.

Comment: @Skaperen - the author specifically asked for credit or removal of their image from the website.  So, to satisfy their terms a credit would be fine and the email/communications logged would be 'good enough' contractually in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Photos are not being used. I took new pics and used them instead. Thanks for the discussion everyone.  I was clueless about this particular law before speaking with you guys. So thank you. My own pics will be used here on out, unless I get permission in writing (if they want me to post their dogs on my site wearing my stuff). Thanks again!!!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

They took the pictures and without any kind of assignment or agreement otherwise they own the copyright - that is the right to say who may and may not reproduce those images.

In this situation, clearly they're a friend of yours to be giving you gifts so there should be no reason why you *wouldn't* at very least put on your site who took the images and a link back to their website/social media page if that's all they're asking - it's not like that will cost you anything...

Comment: She was a good friend at the time, yes.  I had given her a nice Xmas gift and in return she offered to take photos of my dogs for me. She had given me verbal permission to use the photos for whatever I wanted, but now that we aren't close anymore, she has decided otherwise. Thank you for your comment. Very much appreciated

Comment: If she took the photos specifically for you then that is work done under contract regardless of whether there was payment and the rights should already belong to you not her.  Proving it, if it was all verbal, is another matter entirely.

Comment: @JamesRyan in some/many/most jurisdictions a binding contract cannot exist without payment in some form - the permissible forms are very broad and go way beyond money, but there has to be some kind of exchange of value for a contract to exist.

Comment: @NigelHarper "I had given her a nice Xmas gift and in return..." In most jurisdictions that would be classed as a payment if you want to get technical

Comment: Do the same rules apply if the photographer uses someone else's camera and gives the original media to that person, or if e.g. I hand someone my camera and ask them to take a picture of me, do I have free and clear ownership of the picture thus taken?

Comment: @supercat Why would the fact that the equipment used belongs to (and presumably is normally used by) someone else have any bearing on the resulting work's *legal* copyright status? I can't think of any situation in photography where reasonably copyright of the photos would follow from ownership of the equipment. (And what would happen if you, say, borrow a camera body from one person, a lens from another, a flash from a third and a memory card from a fourth person, then have your significant other take a picture of yourself? Slightly contrived example, but possible.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: There are many situations where property may be deemed "abandoned", and I would posit that if some random stranger uses my camera to take my picture, a failure to assert any copyright claims before handing back my camera should be deemed as abandonment of such claims.  I see nothing to be gained by saying that I could almost 100% guaranteed treat the picture as mine unless it happens to get published in a way which is seen by the original photographer and he is somehow able to scrape together evidence (perhaps CCTV footage) showing that he is the person that took it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: BTW, with regard to your contrived example I'd say that the possessor of the original media should be the presumed copyright owner in the absence of any *immediate* claim to the contrary; if e.g. a camera recorded to two cards simultaneously and they were given to two different people, both should be presumed co-owners in the absence of any contrary claim.  By my understanding, in the days of film, original negatives were often considered prima facie evidence of copyright ownership; I'd say exclusive possession of digital information should be considered likewise.

Comment: @JamesRyan I'd say that was questionable and depends on the sequence of events.  If the initial gift was genuine and given without expectation of reward then the fact that the recipient was moved to offer their own gift in return does not make this exchange of gifts into a legal contract.

Comment: @NigelHarper it would very much be a payment not a gift for tax purposes!

Comment: @JamesRyan Again I suggest that would depend on if the tax authorities considered the gifts to be genuine or not.  A genuine exchange of gifts is not taxable (as will be proved in much of the world in about 6 weeks time).

Comment: Pics are no longer being used. That way i don't have to worry about anything. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Payment doesn't matter. The photographer still owns copyright to images the photographer took unless there is an agreement that *specifically* stipulates transfer of copyright. I can sell you prints of my photos all day long. I can sell you digital copies of my photos all day long. I still own the copyright until such time as I assign it to you. Period. Work-for-hire is generally covered because there is an employment contract already signed that specifies who owns the rights to the images I produce under that contract.

Comment: @MichaelClark thats not true. we are not talking about selling, we are talking about when you took the pictures if you took them specifically at the request of someone then they own the copyright.  The difference is did you sell/give the pics then the copyright is yours, did you sell/give the service of photography then the copyright is theirs. If the OP's friend offered the service of taking the pics of her dogs as a gift then the copyright is the OPs.

Comment: JamesRyan You are incorrect. Until the photographer specifically assigns copyright to another party, copyright always belongs to the photographer. Period. It doesn't matter who requested anything. If I offer to provide the service of photography for a wedding I still own the copyright to every image I take of the wedding unless I specifically assign those rights to another party in the contract. Where in the world did you get such an idea?